# concurrent.futures: identify which future returns

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I'm dealing lately with concurrent.futures, I submitted several funcs in one executor , I'd like to know which future returns first.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        future_action = executor.submit(func_action, data)
        future_monitor = executor.submit(func_monitor)
```

now is the main part, I'd like to know that when future_monitor ends , so I would terminate all other action futures.

I've found on docs the following(https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed):

```
concurrent.futures.wait(fs, timeout=None, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
```

, so I can wait to return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED , but how can I assure that it's indeed the monitor future.

tnx in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait), the method `wait` returns two sets: `done`, `not_done` futures.

Check if the future you want to check is in `done` set.

```
fs = future_action, future_monitor
done, not_done = concurrent.futures.wait(fs, timeout=None, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
if future_monitor in done:
    # Do something
```